# Multiple sums of object efficiently d3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, nested, sum

I have a object like:

```
{
  [

      {  id: "AL01",
         list: [
                  { speed : 5
                    value : 10} , 
                  { speed : 7
                    value : 15}
               ]
     }, 
     {  id: "AB01",
        list: [
                { speed : 20
                  value : 1} , 
                { speed : 8
                  value : 10}
              ]
     }

 ]

}
```

and i would like to have this result like:

```
{[ {  id: "AL01", speed: 12, value: 25}, {  id: "AB01", speed: 28, value: 11}]}
```

How can i get this efficiently?
If is it possible to run only one time the functions map or forEach?
I'm wondering something which go by only one time per each object.

Answer (score 2):

Your data structure is not correct. You have to have a property for the outermost array in the data object. Accordingly one can do as follows;

```js
var data = {groups: [ {id: "AL01", list: [{ speed : 5,  value : 10}, { speed : 7, value : 15}]}, {id: "AB01", list: [{ speed : 20, value : 1 }, { speed : 8, value : 10}]}]},
  result = {groups: data.groups.map(g => Object.assign({id: g.id},g.list.reduce((r,c) => ({speed : r.speed + c.speed, value : r.value + c.value}))))};
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some more loops to get the result.

Basically the outer array, then iterate `list` and use another array for the keys. Then collect all data and return a new object with a new structure.

```js
var array = [{ id: "AL01", list: [{ speed: 5, value: 10 }, { speed: 7, value: 15 }] }, { id: "AB01", list: [{ speed: 20, value: 1 }, { speed: 8, value: 10 }] }],
    result = array.map(function (a) {
        var temp = { id: a.id, speed: 0, value: 0 };
        a.list.forEach(function (b) {
            ['speed', 'value'].forEach(function (k) {
                temp[k] += b[k];
            });
        });
        return temp;
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```